# Reply link, auto addition of text to textarea in XHTML Strict?

Tags: javascript, forms, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm trying to add a link next to each comment on my blog, where when you click on the word "Reply", "@Name" automatically adds to the comment form's textarea below (it also jumps to the form by anchor link).

**This is what I'm currently using:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function reply(text) {
    document.form.comment.value += text;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

And for each link (multiple on page)...

```
<a href="#form" onclick="reply('@<?php echo $name; ?>: ');">Reply</a>
```

And the form...

```
<form name="form" id="form"...
<textarea name="comment" id="comment"...
```

Assuming I didn't typo any of it, but it works just fine.

**The problem:**

I'm coding my site in XHTML Strict and upon checking its validation, the `<form>` tag isn't allowed to have a `name` attribute. So now I'm wondering if there's a way I can get around it? Is there another method that doesn't require multiple `<script>`'s for each link? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID on the text area, and use [document.getElementByID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID).